# Multiple lines in onClick?

Tags: javascript

I have a link and I need it to do two thing when it's clicked. First, it tracks the h it using the google tracking code, and the next is that it opens a new window.

I tried:

```
onclick="javascript: pageTracker._trackPageview('/Ads/MMA_Front_Page.com'); window.open(this.href, '_blank'); return false;"
```

But it didn't work, it didn't open a new window.

Did I do something wrong with the code or do I need to create a javascript method and call that?

Thanks

Edit: I am trying with functions, but it wont work. Can you help me please?

Here is the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openAd(adType) {
        pageTracker._trackPageview(adType);
        window.open(this.href, '_blank');
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

And the part where i call it:

```
onclick="openAd('/Ads/MMA_Front_Page.com')"
```

It seems only the first part is working "pageTracker._trackPageview(adType);" and the rest is being ignored.

Comment: What's wrong with creating functions inside your `<script>` tag?

Answer (score 3):

You should really use functions inside your `<script>` tag but, try without the `javascript:..`. like:

```
onclick="pageTracker._trackPageview('/Ads/MMA_Front_Page.com'); window.open(this.href, '_blank'); return false;"
```

Comment: What does your `this.href` show? Try using `alert(this.href);`

Comment: Undefined, it seems this is pointing to the window and to the <a> that called it. Why is this? Maybe I need to use something like "e" in c#? Where "e" is the calling object and it is passed as a parameter?

Comment: If i remove the first line "pageTracker._trackPageview(adType);" the window opens.... weird.

Comment: What about using `document.location.href` instead?. What's the full URL you want to open?

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="do_something();"


<script type="text/javascript">
    function do_something(){
       pageTracker._trackPageview('/Ads/MMA_Front_Page.com'); 
       window.open(this.href, '_blank'); 
       return false;
    }
</script>
```

You have included answer in your question. It will be better to create a function for multiple statement.

Comment: you should add semicolon after function call in onclick